# input 2D vector in main() c++

Tags: c++, vector, stdin

I am novice in vectors, I am tryind to input this 2D vector in main() function, but unable to do so.

```
    int main()
{
    int t, x, n;
        cin>>n;
        vector< vector <int> >  jail(n);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            jail[i].reserve(n);
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                cin>>jail[i][j];
            }
        }   

        cout<< jailBreak(jail,n-1,0,0)<<endl;
}
```

Runtime error is that I need to input an garbage input in the beginning of the program.
This ambiguous input has been bothering me for a long time now, thanx in advance for any advice on this.!

Comment: I tested your program in my machine and it works fine http://ideone.com/KI9f2i

Comment: Use `resize` instead of `reserve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        jail[i].reserve(n);
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            cin>>jail[i][j];
        }
    }
```

---

```
jail[i].reserve(n);
```

should be `jail[i].resize(n)`

```
cin>>jail[i][j]
```

Never seen that work before. `cin` in to a temporary and then push.

```
int temp;
std::cin >> temp;
jail[i].emplace_back(temp);
```

Comment: `cin >> jail[i][j]` is perfectly fine, so long as `resize` was called. The temporary is a waste of time.

Answer (score 5):

this line:

```
jail[i].reserve(n);
```

just tells `vector` to pre-allocate memory (it's just a hint to optimize further reallocs on `push_back` operations but does not guarantee allocation). You have to use `resize` instead which really allocates memory.

Comment: `reserve` actually does guarantee allocation and it's not just a hint.  `resize` also creates objects in the allocated memory.

Comment: you mean it allocates but does not construct the objects (calling their constructor)? in that case, it would not make a difference for `int` types?